# Foundry importing files results in "File not found. Searched the following locations: "" " but does compile

Tags: foundry, vscode

I'm using foundry forge init to setup a new project.

The Counter files which comes built-in when creating a project also have imports: e.g. Counter.t.sol has  "import `../src/Counter.sol";`

When hovering it says `Source "src/Counter.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".solidity(6275)`

It is compiling fine and I'm able to perform the tests. I've even created a new file which I've imported in Counter.sol. It's giving the same error but compiles fine.

Anyone know why this is or how to fix it? I'm able to work while ignoring it but it's just annoying.

Comment: It maybe because of any existing solidity plugin you have, you can consider disabling it and reload your code editor. But yes if its compiling fine then it shouldn't be a problem